# Visual Studio is generating one of my service references with Runtime.Serialization, but the others generate with ServiceModel

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, service-reference

I am generating two service reference contracts for .asmx files in Visual Studio 2010.

I created both service references in an identical fashion. I right click on 'Service References' -> 'Add Service Reference..' -> 'Discover' -> Rename Namespace -> OK.

This is the top most auto-generated code from References.cs for the properly generated service:

```
namespace CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ComponentServicesProxy {
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi", ConfigurationName="ComponentServicesProxy.ComponentServicesSoap")]
    public interface ComponentServicesSoap {
```

This is the code for the improperly generated service:

```
namespace CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.WorkflowServicesProxy {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="OrderDto", Namespace="http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class OrderDto : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

It is clear that WorkflowServicesProxy is using System.Runtime.Serialization where as ComponentServicesProxy is using System.ServiceModel.

I'm unsure what is triggering my second service reference to be generated using System.Runtime.Serialization. Does anyone know what would cause this? My OrderDto class does not have the DataContractAttribute, however, it does have other attributes:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Order"), SoapType("Order")]
public class OrderDto : IDto
```

This service reference was generating code properly before. It seems that between two builds it shifted.

Declarations for both my services are identical:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class WorkflowServices : WebService

[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class ComponentServices : WebService
```

Service reference configurations are identical:

[image]

**Update:** While I tried the suggested answer without success, I have learned some information. If I remove all the code from my asmx file and re-generate the service reference, it DOES swap back to ServiceModel. So, there is something in the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You partially answered your own question

> My OrderDto class does not have the DataContractAttribute

That combined with the fact that I bet that `OrderDTO` resides inside the assembly `CableSolve.Orders` and both the client and server share that assembly.

Because it (technically) is a known type, and it is not explicitly marked as a data contract, the code generator uses the DLL's reference and uses `Runtime.Serialization` to serialize and transfer the object instead of the `ServiceModel`.

[image]

As a "Solution" Change from "Reuse All" to the other option, and check all of the boxes except the one from your referenced common assembly.

Comment: This sounded spot on, but I am not seeing any differences when following your instructions. I attempted to reuse all assemblies except CableSolve.Orders, but the same references.cs was generated. Then I tried again after removing System.Runtime.Serialization from my project, but still the same thing. I'll definitely keep this in mind, though, I suspect you're correct.

Comment: So, it is clear you are correct, but I am struggling still. If I simplify my web service to just one method I am able to control the introduction of Runtime.Serialization by referencing / removing the reference to my DTO object. However, your suggest solution does not affect anything. I'll continue to tinker with it.

Comment: If you are not using a common class that is serializeable then (I think) you still need to mark any DTO's as `DataContract`s so they can be sent over the wire correctly.

Comment: It was my understanding that DataContract and Serializable have very similar functionality and that the only difference is that DataContract is opt-in where as Serializable is opt-out. Could you please explain why a DataContract would assist in serializing the data properly?

Comment: After doing research, I was mistaken. However, now I am curious, what problem is having OrderDto not be a DataContract giving you?

Comment: No problems there. I would happily use DataContract over Serializable if it provided some benefit. My issue is with the compiler using Runtime.Serialization instead of System.ServiceModel. Runtime.Serialization converts int[] to ArrayOfInt. I do not want an end user to have to provide an ArrayOfInt object to my service method as a parameter.